# App is crashing with shared preferences

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to set drawables on right in edittext with shared preferences, but I don't know where I went wrong, it's crashing on start of the activity.

I want that it changes the drawable based on onClick of button, save it to shared preference (so it will stay there until the user change it again) and then change the drawable based on shared preference.

Here is activity:

```
package com.wishlist.bow;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class ActivitySetup extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String mena = "euro";

SharedPreferences menaPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = menaPref.edit();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_setup);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    EditText edittextSrc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.howMuch);

    if (menaPref.contains("dollar"))
    {
        edittextSrc.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.dollar, 0);
    }

    if (menaPref.contains("euro"))
    {
        edittextSrc.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.euro, 0);
    }

    if (menaPref.contains("koruny"))
    {
        edittextSrc.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.koruny, 0);
    }

    if (menaPref.contains("libra"))
    {
        edittextSrc.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.libra, 0);
    }
}

public void confirm(View view){

}

public void euro(View view){

    String euro = "euro";

    editor.putString(mena, euro);
    editor.commit();

}

public void dollar(View view){

    String dollar = "dollar";

    editor.putString(mena, dollar);
    editor.commit();

}

public void koruny(View view){

    String koruny = "koruny";

    editor.putString(mena, koruny);
    editor.commit();
}

public void libra(View view){

    String libra = "libra";

    editor.putString(mena, libra);
    editor.commit();

}
}
```

Here is crash log:

```
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394): Process: com.wishlist.bow, PID: 9394
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.wishlist.bow/com.wishlist.bow.ActivitySetup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at com.wishlist.bow.ActivitySetup.<init>(ActivitySetup.java:17)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
12-23 17:00:15.277: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getApplicationContext() is available after onCreate or onStart but not this way. please init your sharedPreferences in onCreate.

Like this

```
SharedPreferences menaPref;
Editor editor;

public void onCreate(..){
    menaPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = menaPref.edit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that help, now it doesn't crash, but it's not working. Do you see some problem?

Comment: try to add some Logs and read it, try to learn how to use the debugger and the logcat. I think your preferences do not contain anything of the values

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a method before its available.

Put this on class level

```
SharedPreferences menaPref;
Editor editor;
```

and in onCreate use this

```
menaPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = menaPref.edit();
```

Answer (score 3):

it is only an idea, but try to move the

```
menaPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to the onCreate.