# Restore the app state after it is open again android development

Tags: android

I modified the [BLE app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt)  so that  it plots data that's coming from a sensor, shown below:
[image]

Now, when I close the app I want to be able to save the plot, so that next time when I open the app again, I can continue plot the graph instead of starting over.

I googled around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006431/5186878) person recommending using [Icepick](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick) library to save the app state. I tried his method but it didn't work, maybe I am using it wrong.

I added the @state variables at the top, added the @overide function and added the restoreInstanceState() function in my onCreate. Then I tried to store the last x and y value into the @state variables that I declared at the top of my code. Following is my code structure in DeviceControlActivity.java.

```
public class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @State int saved_x_axies = 0;
    @State int saved_y_axies = 0;
    ...
   @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
   }

   ...
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.button_control);
      Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
      // double y, x;
     Log.d("array","array ---> " + saved_y_axies);
     ...
   }
   ...
       private void displayData(TextView dataField, String data) {
    if (data != null) {
        dataField.setText(data);
        if(dataField == ch1DataField) {
            String[] parts = data.split(" ");
            int ch1data =  Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            series0.appendData(new DataPoint(X_axies++, ch1data), true, 33);
            saved_y_axies = ch1data;
            saved_x_axies = X_axies;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Question 1, saved_y_axies gives me zero when I print it out using Log.d. From my code structure, is this how I am suppose to use the icepick library, if not can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Question 2, can icepick library store int arrays? ultimately, I am thinking of storing all the sensor data into an array, when the app opens again, I am going to re-plot all the values to get the original graph back.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are closing your app then how it maintain your state, You should use shared preference or database for such

Comment: This is an everyday Android question that has been answered here *many* times before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463758/5186878
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624068/app-is-crashing-with-shared-preferences
these two links saved me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using  SharedPreferences to save and get values:

global variable:

> public SharedPreferences pref;

inside oncreate():

> pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

```
     //saves the array using shared preference key, value pairs
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = pref.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("ARRAY_KEY_MID", json);
    prefsEditor.putString("ARRAY_KEY_AIR", json_air);
    prefsEditor.putString("ARRAY_KEY_DEEP", json_deep);
    //saves the x axeies
    prefsEditor.putInt("INT_KEY", X_axies);
    Log.d("close", "array------> " + json);
    prefsEditor.commit();


    ////retrive all the values using the keys
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_clear = pref.edit();
    X_axies = pref.getInt("INT_KEY", 0);
    String json = pref.getString("ARRAY_KEY_MID", "");
    String json_air = pref.getString("ARRAY_KEY_AIR", "");
    String json_deep = pref.getString("ARRAY_KEY_DEEP", "");
```